# How to force the unmanaged to managed calls to use the default appdomain?

Tags: appdomain

I have been trying to fix this issue for quite sometime now. I have a C# user control wrapping an activex control (through wrappers created by RCW); This particular activex control loads MFC extension dll which has got C# WPF assembly dependant. This MFC extension dll calls C# WPF assembly through classes compiled as managed (using /clr compiler option).

The problem here is that - when my C# user control gets loaded in C#; It gets into the default app domain and everything seems to be working fine; but whenever a call is made from unmanaged part of MFC extension dll to the managed portion of it, it cramps to find the C# WPF assembly. I googled to find that there seems another appdomain getting created when a call is made from unmanaged portion of MFC extension dll to the managed portion. Right now, I am clueless about this one - How to force the unmanaged to managed calls to use the default appdomain?